# How do you make a tab control look like it does in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, tabcontrol

I'm trying to make a UI, with elements that resemble Visual Studio.  For example, I want my horizontal and vertical tabs, to look like this:

[image]

You can't in a Winform.  So, I was like ... They probably added that in WPF.  Nope.

Comment: You will need to owner-draw it.

Comment: Worth noting that it's not a tab group per se, they are dockable windows. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2247402/implementing-a-multidock-window-system-like-blend-visual-studio-in-wpf

Comment: If it's just about the appearance, you need to draw it yourself but if you need more functionality, like drag and drop, floating and docking, you probably are looking for [DockPanel Suite](http://dockpanelsuite.com).

Comment: You are correct in that the modern Visual Studio UI is done with WPF.  The exact controls they made are not publicly available though, so even if you switch to WPF, recreating them exactly would be a challenge.  It is also technically possible implement them in WinForms, but that implementation would be done very differently than how it would be done with WPF.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Edit: Code rewrite and posted below**

Not wanting to do it by hand, which I knew I had to, I spent a few minutes and created this:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security.Permissions;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using static VisualStudioLikeControls.misc;

namespace VisualStudioLikeControls
{
    //TODO:
    //      ADD a multi-tab select system
    [
        ComVisible(true), ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDispatch),
        DefaultProperty("TabPages"), DefaultEvent("SelectedIndexChanged")
    ]
    public partial class VSTabControl : TabControl
    {
        [Category("Custom"), Description("The color used for the components background."), DefaultValue(typeof(Color), "0, 0, 0")]
        public Color Background { get; set; } = Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0);

        [Category("Custom"), Description("The color used for the components tab background.  Only fully shows, if the tabs background color is set to transparent."), DefaultValue(typeof(Color), "0, 0, 0")]
        public Color BackgroundTab { get; set; } = Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0);

        [Category("Custom"), Description("The color used for the components border."), DefaultValue(typeof(Color), "0, 122, 204")]
        public Color Border { get; set; } = Color.FromArgb(0, 122, 204);

        [Category("Custom"), Description("Indicates whether or not you the components Tabpages Headers have border edges."), DefaultValue(true)]
        public bool BorderEdges { get; set; } = true;

        private int _BorderSize = 1;
        [Category("Custom"), Description("The size of the components border."), DefaultValue(1)]
        public int BorderSize
        {
            get => _BorderSize;
            set => _BorderSize = value.LimitToRange(1, 2); //Two is the largest it can be.  Anymore won't be seen.
        }

        [Category("Custom"), Description("The color used for the components Active tabs color."), DefaultValue(typeof(Color), "0, 122, 204")]
        public Color ActiveTab { get; set; } = Color.FromArgb(0, 122, 204);

        [Category("Custom"), Description("The color used for the components Alternative tab indicator color.\nUsage : Set the Tag property of the desired TabPage(s) to 1."), DefaultValue(typeof(Color), "OrangeRed")]
        public Color AlternativeTab { get; set; } = Color.OrangeRed;

        [Category("Custom"), Description("The color used for the components InActive tabs color."), DefaultValue(typeof(Color), "0, 0, 0")]
        public Color InActiveTab { get; set; } = Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0);

        [Category("Custom"), Description("The color used for the components Active Tab Indicator."), DefaultValue(typeof(Color), "0, 122, 204")]
        public Color ActiveIndicator { get; set; } = Color.FromArgb(0, 122, 204);
        [Category("Custom"), Description("The color used for the components InActive Tab Indicator."), DefaultValue(typeof(Color), "0, 122, 204")]
        public Color InActiveIndicator { get; set; } = Color.FromArgb(0, 122, 204);
        [Category("Custom"), Description("The size of the components Indicator."), DefaultValue(6)]
        public int IndicatorSize { get; set; } = 6; //Might become obsolete

        [Category("Custom"), Description("The color used for the components Divider."), DefaultValue(typeof(Color), "0, 122, 204")]
        public Color Divider { get; set; } = Color.FromArgb(0, 122, 204);

        private int _DividerSize = 2;
        [Category("Custom"), Description("The size of the components Divider."), DefaultValue(2)]
        public int DividerSize
        {
            get => _DividerSize;
            set => _DividerSize = value.LimitToRange(1, 2);
        }

        [Category("Custom"), Description("The color used for the components Active tabs text."), DefaultValue(typeof(Color), "255, 255, 255")]
        public Color ActiveText { get; set; } = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255);
        [Category("Custom"), Description("The color used for the components InActive tabs text."), DefaultValue(typeof(Color), "255, 255, 255")]
        public Color InActiveText { get; set; } = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255);

        [Category("Custom"), Description("Indicates whether or not you can rearrange the components Tabpages.  CLICK on the Tabpages HEADER with the LEFT mousebutton and HOLD DOWN the <SHIFT> KEY, to drag it LEFT or RIGHT."), DefaultValue(false)]
        public bool CanDrag { get; set; }

        StringFormat format = new StringFormat { Alignment = StringAlignment.Center };

        private Bitmap bitDrag = default(Bitmap);

        private bool bDrag, bMouseDown, bShiftKey;
        private Point ptPreviousLocation, ptMaxDrag;
        private int DraggedIndex = -1;

        protected override CreateParams CreateParams
        {
            [SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Flags = SecurityPermissionFlag.UnmanagedCode)]
            get
            {                
                CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
                cp.ExStyle |= 0x02000000;  // Turn on WS_EX_COMPOSITED to stop flicker
                return cp;
            }
        }

        public VSTabControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint | ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer |
                     ControlStyles.UserPaint | ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw | ControlStyles.CacheText, true);

            Alignment = TabAlignment.Top;

            Margin = new Padding(0);
            Padding = new Point(0, 0);

            Font = new Font("Leelawadee UI", Font.Size);
        }

        private void SetDragState() => bDrag = (CanDrag && bMouseDown && bShiftKey);

        protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            bMouseDown = true;

            SetDragState();

            Rectangle rectDrag = GetTabRect(SelectedIndex);

            ptPreviousLocation = new Point(rectDrag.X, rectDrag.Y);

            rectDrag.Width += 1; rectDrag.Height += 1;

            Bitmap src = new Bitmap(Width, Height);

            DrawToBitmap(src, ClientRectangle);

            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitDrag = new Bitmap(rectDrag.Width, rectDrag.Height)))
            {
                g.DrawImage(src, new Rectangle(0, 0, bitDrag.Width, bitDrag.Height), rectDrag, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
            }
        }

        protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (bDrag)
            {
                if (Alignment == TabAlignment.Top || Alignment == TabAlignment.Bottom)
                {
                    ptPreviousLocation = new Point(((e.X < 0) ? 0 : (e.X > ptMaxDrag.X) ? ptMaxDrag.X : e.X), (Alignment == TabAlignment.Top ? BorderSize : ptMaxDrag.Y));
                }

                if (Alignment == TabAlignment.Right || Alignment == TabAlignment.Left)
                {
                    ptPreviousLocation = new Point(ptMaxDrag.X, ((e.Y < 0) ? 0 : (e.Y > ptMaxDrag.Y) ? ptMaxDrag.Y : e.Y));
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < TabCount; i++)
                {
                    if (GetTabRect(i).Contains(PointToClient(Cursor.Position))) { DraggedIndex = i; break; }
                }

                Invalidate();
            }
        }

        protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            void SwapTabPages(TabPage inDestTab)
            {
                int SourceIndex = TabPages.IndexOf(SelectedTab);
                int DestinationIndex = TabPages.IndexOf(inDestTab);

                TabPages[DestinationIndex] = SelectedTab;
                TabPages[SourceIndex] = inDestTab;

                if (SelectedIndex == SourceIndex) { SelectedIndex = DestinationIndex; }
                else if (SelectedIndex == DestinationIndex) { SelectedIndex = SourceIndex; }
            }

            bDrag = bMouseDown = false;

            if (DraggedIndex > -1)
            {
                SwapTabPages(TabPages[DraggedIndex]);

                DraggedIndex = -1;
            }

            SetDragState();

            Invalidate();
        }

        protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs ke) { bShiftKey = ke.Shift; SetDragState(); }

        protected override void OnKeyUp(KeyEventArgs e) { bDrag = bShiftKey = false; SetDragState(); }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            if (DesignMode) return;

            e.Graphics.Clear(Background); //Background

            Rectangle container = new Rectangle(0, 0, Width - (BorderSize % 2), Height - (BorderSize % 2));
            Rectangle containerHead = default(Rectangle);

            if (TabCount > 0)
            {
                using (SolidBrush brushBackgroundTab = new SolidBrush(BackgroundTab))
                using (SolidBrush brushDivider = new SolidBrush(Divider))
                {
                    //Draws the background of the tab control
                    {
                        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brushBackgroundTab, DisplayRectangle);
                    }

                    //Divider Line
                    {
                        Rectangle rectDivider = GetTabRect(SelectedIndex);

                        if (Alignment == TabAlignment.Top || Alignment == TabAlignment.Bottom)
                        {
                            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brushDivider,
                                                     0,
                                                     (((Alignment == TabAlignment.Top) ? (TabPages[SelectedIndex].Top - DividerSize - (DividerSize % 2)) :
                                                     (TabPages[SelectedIndex].Bottom + (DividerSize % 2)))),
                                                     (Width - BorderSize), DividerSize                                                     
                                                    );
                        }

                        if (Alignment == TabAlignment.Right || Alignment == TabAlignment.Left)
                        {
                            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brushDivider,
                                                     ((Alignment == TabAlignment.Right) ? (TabPages[SelectedIndex].Right + (DividerSize % 2)) : TabPages[SelectedIndex].Left - DividerSize - (DividerSize % 2)),
                                                     BorderSize,
                                                     DividerSize,
                                                     (Height - (BorderSize * 2))
                                                     );
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            using (Pen penActive = new Pen(ActiveTab))
            using (Pen penBorder = new Pen(Border, BorderSize))
            using (SolidBrush brushActive = new SolidBrush(ActiveTab))
            using (SolidBrush brushInActive = new SolidBrush(InActiveTab))
            using (SolidBrush brushAlternative = new SolidBrush(AlternativeTab))
            using (SolidBrush brushActiveIndicator = new SolidBrush(ControlPaint.Light(ActiveIndicator, .75f)))
            using (SolidBrush brushInActiveIndicator = new SolidBrush(InActiveIndicator))
            using (SolidBrush brushActiveText = new SolidBrush(ActiveText))
            using (SolidBrush brushInActiveText = new SolidBrush(InActiveText))
            using (SolidBrush brushDrag = new SolidBrush(ControlPaint.Dark(ActiveTab, .5f)))
            {
                penBorder.Alignment = penActive.Alignment = PenAlignment.Inset; //Only way to set the proper alignment, that I know of

                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(penBorder, container); //Border

                if (TabCount > 0)
                {
                    ptMaxDrag = new Point(0, 0);

                    for (int i = 0; i < TabCount; i++)
                    {
                        containerHead = GetTabRect(i);

                        e.Graphics.FillRectangle((SelectedIndex == i) ? (bDrag ? brushDrag : brushActive) : brushInActive, containerHead); //Header Background

                        //Header Edges
                        if (BorderEdges && (i == SelectedIndex))
                        {
                            Point ptA = new Point(0, 0); Point ptB = new Point(0, 0);
                            Point ptC = new Point(0, 0); Point ptD = new Point(0, 0);

                            ptA.X = ptB.X = ptD.X = containerHead.X;
                            ptA.Y = ptB.Y = ptC.Y = containerHead.Y;
                            ptA.Y = ptC.Y = ptD.Y = containerHead.Y + containerHead.Height - 1;

                            if (Alignment == TabAlignment.Top || Alignment == TabAlignment.Bottom)
                            {
                                ptD.X = ptC.X = containerHead.X + containerHead.Width;
                                ptC.Y = containerHead.Y;

                                if (Alignment == TabAlignment.Bottom)
                                {
                                    Swap(ref ptA, ref ptB); Swap(ref ptC, ref ptD);
                                }
                            }

                            if (Alignment == TabAlignment.Right || Alignment == TabAlignment.Left)
                            {
                                ptA.Y = containerHead.Y;
                                ptB.X = ptC.X = containerHead.X + containerHead.Width - 1;

                                if (Alignment == TabAlignment.Left)
                                {
                                    Swap(ref ptA, ref ptC); Swap(ref ptB, ref ptD);
                                }
                            }

                            e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(ControlPaint.Light(brushActive.Color)), ptA, ptB);
                            e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(ControlPaint.Light(brushActive.Color)), ptB, ptC);
                            e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(ControlPaint.Dark(brushActive.Color)), ptC, ptD);
                        }

                        //Indicator
                        {
                            Rectangle rectDivider = default(Rectangle);

                            if (Alignment == TabAlignment.Top || Alignment == TabAlignment.Bottom)
                            {
                                rectDivider = new Rectangle(containerHead.X, containerHead.Y + ((Alignment == TabAlignment.Top) ? containerHead.Height : -DividerSize), containerHead.Width, DividerSize);
                            }
                            if (Alignment == TabAlignment.Right || Alignment == TabAlignment.Left)
                            {
                                rectDivider = new Rectangle(containerHead.X - ((Alignment == TabAlignment.Right) ? DividerSize : -containerHead.Width), containerHead.Y, DividerSize, containerHead.Height); //Indicator
                            }

                            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(((TagToInt(TabPages[i]) == 1) ? brushAlternative : ((i == SelectedIndex) ? brushActiveIndicator : brushInActiveIndicator)), rectDivider);
                        }

                        //Text
                        if (!(bDrag && i == SelectedIndex))
                        {
                            int angle = 0;
                            {
                                if (Alignment == TabAlignment.Right) angle = 90;
                                if (Alignment == TabAlignment.Left) angle = 270;
                            }

                            float w, h;

                            w = h = 0f;

                            if (Alignment == TabAlignment.Top || Alignment == TabAlignment.Bottom) { w = containerHead.X + (containerHead.Width / 2); }
                            if (Alignment == TabAlignment.Right || Alignment == TabAlignment.Left) { w = containerHead.X; h = containerHead.Y + (containerHead.Height / 2); }

                            if (Alignment == TabAlignment.Top || Alignment == TabAlignment.Bottom) { h = containerHead.Y + ((Alignment == TabAlignment.Top) ? IndicatorSize : 0) + ((containerHead.Height - IndicatorSize) / 2); }
                            if (Alignment == TabAlignment.Right || Alignment == TabAlignment.Left) { w += (((Alignment == TabAlignment.Right) ? 0 : IndicatorSize) + ((containerHead.Width - IndicatorSize) / 2)); }

                            e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(w, h);
                            {
                                Size textSize = e.Graphics.MeasureString(TabPages[i].Text, Font).ToSize();

                                e.Graphics.RotateTransform(angle);
                                e.Graphics.DrawString(TabPages[i].Text, Font, ((SelectedIndex == i) ? brushActiveText : brushInActiveText), new PointF((-textSize.Width / 2f), (-textSize.Height / 2f)));
                            }
                            e.Graphics.ResetTransform();
                        }

                        if (bMouseDown)
                        {
                            if (Alignment == TabAlignment.Top || Alignment == TabAlignment.Bottom) { if (i > 0) { ptMaxDrag.X += GetTabRect(i).Width; } }
                            if (Alignment == TabAlignment.Top) { ptMaxDrag.Y = BorderSize; }
                            if (Alignment == TabAlignment.Bottom) { ptMaxDrag.Y = containerHead.Y; };

                            if (Alignment == TabAlignment.Right || Alignment == TabAlignment.Left) { ptMaxDrag.X = containerHead.X; if (i > 0) { ptMaxDrag.Y += containerHead.Height; } }
                        }

                        if (bDrag && (bitDrag != null)) { e.Graphics.DrawImage(bitDrag, new Point(ptPreviousLocation.X, ptPreviousLocation.Y)); }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Helper class**

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace VisualStudioLikeControls
{
    static class misc
    {
        /// <summary> Essentially ... clamp </summary>
        public static int LimitToRange(this int value, int inclusiveMinimum, int inclusiveMaximum)
        {
            if (value < inclusiveMinimum) { return inclusiveMinimum; }
            if (value > inclusiveMaximum) { return inclusiveMaximum; }
            return value;
        }

        /// <summary> Swap function that uses <Generics>. </summary>
        public static void Swap<T>(ref T a, ref T b)
        {
            T temp = a;
            a = b; b = temp;
        }

        /// <summary> Converts the <Tag> property of a control to an integer. </summary>
        public static int TagToInt(object inObject) => Convert.ToInt32((inObject as Control).Tag);
    }
}
```

**Progress, so far:**

[image]

Comment: This gives me the error `VSTabControl does not contain a definition for 'AutoScaleMode'`

Comment: @mrid, delete AutoScaleMode line